# Parse server 'released in production' / environment

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I've just transferred an existing Parse server to my self hosted Digital Ocean droplet. Unfortunately, I cannot get the sending push messages part working. I still remember that in the old Parse.com, we had an option to release the app in production. But I cannot find that attribute anymore.

Is there any way to set the parse server environment to "production" in my config or so?

Cheers,
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

You can set that in your parse-server config!

```
{ "ios": [ { "pfx": "/home/parse/file/ApplePushServices.p12", "bundleId": "yourApp", "production": true } ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below config to parse server.

```
    var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'databaseUrl',
  cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'your app id',
  masterKey: 'master key',
  serverURL:'Server url', 
    push : {
        ios: {
            cert: 'ios certificate url',
            bundleId: 'Your bundle id',
            production: true
      }
    }
});
```